# Drawing will be cleared after minimizing window vc++ mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, drawing, gdi

I have written this program, but when I minimize the window, all the drawing will be cleared. what should I do?

```
        CClientDC dc(this);
        dc.Ellipse(point.x-20,point.y-20,point.x+20,point.y+20);
        c[n][1] = point.x; c[n][2] = point.y;
```

who can help me solving this problem?

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean when you restore *after* having minimized the window.

Normally, in MFC you should do your drawing in the view's `OnDraw` member function (so you almost never need to use `CClientDC` as you have). Anything else that wants something drawn will put data describing what needs to be drawn into the Document object, and then call `UpdateAllViews` to get the new data drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function of your above code and call it from `OnDraw` function. It will work fine.